# Notification of structured data quality guidelines penalty, but no manual action

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data

I got a notification in Google's Search Console stating:

> Google has detected structured markup on some of your pages that violates our structured data quality guidelines. In order to ensure
>   quality search results for users, we display rich search results only
>   for content that uses markup that conforms to our quality guidelines.
>   This manual action has been applied to zippi.co.uk/ . We suggest that
>   you fix your markup and file a reconsideration request. Once we
>   determine that the markup on the pages is compliant with our
>   guidelines, we will remove this manual action.
>
> Here’s how to fix this problem:
>
> **1** Update your markup to follow our structured data guidelines Fix erroneous markup or remove markup that does not accurately represent
>   the content of your page.
>
> **2** Submit a reconsideration request. Once you fix your site, file for reconsideration to remove this manual action. Include any details
>   or documentation that can help us understand the changes made to your
>   site.

I have fixed the suspected issue but when I go to submit a reconsideration request it says there have been no manual action taken.

What does this mean? Was this not a manual action? And what should I do next?

Comment: Sometimes Googles Search Console is a bit slow. It may take an additional day or two more before a manual action shows up online. I have seen e-mails show up before the online notice before. Let's hope this is the case. Otherwise, I am not sure what to say. Sorry. Cheers!!

Comment: Hi @closetnoc you are right, it has been 2 days and the form has become available.